# Replace a view in a Autolayout NSConstraints setup

Tags: ios

I have used only NSConstraints in Interface Builder to setup a view. Now I have a StackView that I want to animate out. This causes all the Layout to be misplaced.

1. I have tried to replace the view(StackView) with a temp(with the same frame), but that did not work.
2. I have also tried to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`
3. also tried the following:

   ```
   self.numbers_Top_Constraint.constant = self.topscreen.frame.size.height
   self.topscreen.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

       self.topscreen.layoutIfNeeded()
   ```

   }

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use constraints instead of changing frames.
Set a top margin constraint to stack view and then change it before the animation and call self.view.layoutIfNeeded().
Something like this -

```
self.numbersStackViewTopMarginConstriant.constant = self.view.frame.size.height
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (Bool) in
```

Comment: Thanks, though it did not work - I update the question with you suggestion.

Comment: are you creating the views programmatically ? 
Also check if the view height is correct while assigning to constraint